# prevent jetty from scanning some files

Tags: jetty, scanning

jetty error message: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file zz1.class`

Actually `zz1.class` is used for my custom ClassLoader, that is to say common ClassLoader cannot parse it. How to request jetty not scan `zz1.class`? The error causes the whole web application down. thx!

Answer (score 0):

well, i didn't get a solution to solve the question, but i made a trick to cheat jetty. I changed the zz1.class to zz1.clasz, so jetty ignored parsing the file.